# Android Local broadcast is not working from JobService

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to send broadcast from JobService and receiving it from an activity .

Here is what I have tried

**MyJobService**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
       if (!HomeActivity.isOpen) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(intent);
       } else {
          Intent sendNoti = new Intent("location_turned_off");
          sendBroadcast(sendNoti);
       }
       jobFinished(params, false);
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in my Activity

```
public static boolean isOpen;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   isOpen = true;
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(locationTurnedOff,new IntentFilter("location_turned_off"));
}
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      isOpen = false;          
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(locationTurnedOff);                                                      
    }



private BroadcastReceiver locationTurnedOff = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("onReceive","Broadcast received");//nothing is triggered here
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

I am sending broadcast conditionally, I am sending broadcast if the activity is onResume state

Comment: Is your `Activity` running In the foreground when that broadcast occurs?

Comment: You need to make sure that the Activity is on resume state. If it already call onPause(), then the activity won't listen to broadcast again

Comment: @MikeM. yes, I am sending broadcast conditionally chek my edit

Comment: @SidhiArtha I am sure that activity is on resume state, check my edit

Comment: OK, then you just need to make sure to send the broadcast on the `LocalBroadcastManager`, not a `Context`. I would also mention that `LocalBroadcastManager#sendBroadcast()` returns a `boolean` that'll tell you if a broadcast has been sent successfully - i.e., is there's an appropriate Receiver currently registered - so you could use that instead of your static `isOpen` flag. Just FYI.